# UnderscoreJs : objects sortBy with empty attributes

Tags: sorting, underscore.js, lodash

Problem is, I want to sort by price an array of users that might contains empty attributes like this one:

```
var array =  [
    {
      "created": "2015-11-27T16:33:46.781Z",
      "name": "Johan",
      "pricing": {
        "base_price" : "12",
        "price_by_hour" : "5"
      }
    },
    {
      "created": "2015-11-27T16:33:46.781Z",
      "name": "Marco"
    },
    {
      "created": "2015-11-27T16:33:46.781Z",
      "name": "Jane",
      "pricing": {
        "base_price" : "8",
        "price_by_hour" : "11"
      }
    }
 ];

array = _.sortBy(array, function(item) {
    return item.pricing.base_price;
});
```

console.log(array);

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'base_price' of undefined
```

How can I put the items without the **pricing** object at the bottom of my list and still sorting it?

In this case, I want to sort the list with Jane first, then Johan, then Marco.

Comment: Please note that your prices are strings. This impacts directly in your `sortBy` function, because `"12" < "8"`, but obviously `12 > 8`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an easy way to do it:

```
_.sortBy(array, 'pricing.base_price');
```

When you pass a string as an iteratee to [sortBy()](https://lodash.com/docs#sortBy), the [property()](https://lodash.com/docs#property) function is used. This function works with property paths and simply returns `undefined` if the property doesn't exist.

Comment: Best and dry-er answer so far.

Answer (score 3):

Just put a conditional

```
array = _.sortBy(array, function(item){
    if(item.pricing){
       return item.pricing.base_price;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, I just had to return false if the attribute is empty:

```
array = _.sortBy(array, function(item) {
    if(!item.pricing || !item.pricing.base_price){
         return -1;
    }
    return item.pricing.base_price;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a conditional to avoid getting `TypeError`. Also you need to cast `base_price` to `Number` to get a proper sorting.

```
array = _.sortBy(array, function(item){
    if(item.pricing){
       return Number(item.pricing.base_price);
    }
});
```

One alternative would be already initate them as `Number`.

```
var array =  [
    {
      "created": "2015-11-27T16:33:46.781Z",
      "name": "Johan",
      "pricing": {
        "base_price" : 12,
        "price_by_hour" : 5
      }
    },
    {
      "created": "2015-11-27T16:33:46.781Z",
      "name": "Marco"
    },
    {
      "created": "2015-11-27T16:33:46.781Z",
      "name": "Jane",
      "pricing": {
        "base_price" : 8,
        "price_by_hour" : 11
      }
    }
 ];

array = _.sortBy(array, function(item) {
    if(item.pricing){
       return item.pricing.base_price;
    }
});
```